# LTR item in beamer-rl

Tags: beamer, itemize, babel, right-to-left

I am creating a presentation in beamer-rl. sometimes I have English item but the itemize environment is RTL.

This is an example:

```
\documentclass[babel={layout=lists},9pt]{beamer-rl}

\babelprovide[import,main,mapdigits]{persian}
\babelfont{sf}{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 
            این یک تست است!
            
            \item 
            This is a test!
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want the result to look like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you make a sketch of how the result should look like? Should the bullet point of the LTR item be on the left or right side?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz For Persian the bullet point should be on the right and for English on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch to English for the item:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[babel={layout=lists},9pt]{beamer-rl}

\babelprovide[import,main,mapdigits]{persian}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 
            این یک تست است!
            
            \begin{otherlanguage}{english}
            \item 
            This is a test!
            \end{otherlanguage}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]